# How do I create a string of array combinations given a list of "source code" strings?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, python-2.7, recursion, dynamic

Basically, I’m given a list of strings such as:

```
["structA.structB.myArr[6].myVar",
"structB.myArr1[4].myArr2[2].myVar",
"structC.myArr1[3][4].myVar",
"structA.myArr1[4]",
"structA.myVar"]
```

These strings are describing variables/arrays from multiple structs. The integers in the arrays describe the size each array. Given a string has a/multiple arrays (1d or 2d), I want to generate a list of strings which go through each index combination in the array for that string. I thought of using for loops but issue is I don’t know how many arrays are in a given string before running the script. So I couldn’t do something like

```
for i in range (0, idx1):
    for j in range (0, idx2):
         for k in range (0, idx3):
               arr.append(“structA.myArr1[%i][%i].myArr[%i]” %(idx1,idx2,idx3))
```

but the issue is that I don’t know how I can create multiple/dynamic for loops based on how many indexes and  how I could create a dynamic append statement that changes per each string from the original list since each string will have a different number of indexes and the arrays will be in different locations of the string.

I was able to write a regex to find all the index for each string in my list of strings:

```
indexArr = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', myString)
//after looping, indexArr = [['6'],['4','2'],['3','4'],['4']]
```

however I'm really stuck on how to achieve the "dynamic for loops" or use recursion for this. I want to get my ending list of strings to look like:

```
[
["structA.structB.myArr[0].myVar",
"structA.structB.myArr[1].myVar",
...
"structA.structB.myArr[5].myVar”],

[“structB.myArr1[0].myArr2[0].myVar",
"structB.myArr1[0].myArr2[1].myVar",
"structB.myArr1[1].myArr2[0].myVar",
…
"structB.myArr1[3].myArr2[1].myVar”],

[“structC.myArr1[0][0].myVar",
"structC.myArr1[0][1].myVar",
…
"structC.myArr1[2][3].myVar”],

[“structA.myArr1[0]”,
…
"structA.myArr1[3]”],

[“structA.myVar”] //this will only contain 1 string since there were no arrays
]
```

I am really stuck on this, any help is appreciated. Thank you so much.

Comment: It's a bit confusing what your input and what your output is. If the input is already an array of such strings, why do you need an output like that? Is the goal to evaluate what the input is referring to?

Comment: the input is an array of various strings which represent source code, however, they have arrays which contain the size of the array. For example, "structA.myArr[4]". I want to expand that string to get an entire set of source code that accounts for all combinations of the array. So from "structA.myArr[4]" I want to get "structA.myArr[0]","structA.myArr[1]","structA.myArr[2]","structA.myArr[3]". The input is already an array of strings but each one refers to it's own set of source code and needs to have a combination of its arrays like the example above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to use `itertools.product` to generate all possible combinations of a set of ranges and substitute them as array indices of an appropriately constructed string template.

```
import itertools
import re
def expand(code):
    p = re.compile('\[(.*?)\]')
    ranges = [range(int(s)) for s in p.findall(code)]
    template = p.sub("[{}]", code)
    result = [template.format(*s) for s in itertools.product(*ranges)]
    return result
```

The result of `expand("structA.structB.myArr[6].myVar")` is

```
['structA.structB.myArr[0].myVar',
 'structA.structB.myArr[1].myVar',
 'structA.structB.myArr[2].myVar',
 'structA.structB.myArr[3].myVar',
 'structA.structB.myArr[4].myVar',
 'structA.structB.myArr[5].myVar']
```

and `expand("structB.myArr1[4].myArr2[2].myVar")` is

```
['structB.myArr1[0].myArr2[0].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[0].myArr2[1].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[1].myArr2[0].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[1].myArr2[1].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[2].myArr2[0].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[2].myArr2[1].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[3].myArr2[0].myVar',
 'structB.myArr1[3].myArr2[1].myVar']
```

and the corner case `expand("structA.myVar")` naturally works to produce

```
['structA.myVar']
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for! And a very clean, precise solution that accounts for the corner case as well. I haven't used itertools much but it looks like it is very powerful. Thank you!